# xpath (unknown, character varying) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I'm trying to get some data out of a PostgreSQL table incidents_data

```
                              Table public.incidents_data
  Column   |          Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 mib_name  | character varying(64)   |           | extended |              |
 timestamp | bigint                  | not null  | plain    |              |
 node_id   | bigint                  | not null  | plain    |              |
 id        | bigint                  | not null  | plain    |              |
 xml_data  | character varying(4096) |           | extended |              |
 cause     | character varying(128)  |           | extended |              |
```

The data is in column xml_data with the following XML layout.

```xml
<Incident>
<ExtraInformation>
<SslState>error</SslState>
<RemoteLocalTuple>Remote Ip:Port 1.1.1.1:46537  &lt;---&gt;  Local Ip:Port 2.2.2.2:5061</RemoteLocalTuple>
</ExtraInformation>
<StandardInfo>
<Cause>error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired</Cause>
<MIBName>ipcsTlsHandshakeFailure</MIBName>
<Timestamp>1594933477674</Timestamp>
<IncidenceId>797466738837365</IncidenceId>
<Source>source-server</Source>
</StandardInfo>
</Incident>
```

Trying to get the RemoteLocalTuple data using xpath like below.

```
select xpath('/mydefns:Incident/mydefns:ExtraInformation/mydefbs:RemoteLocalTuple', xml_data) from incidents_data where mib_name='ipcsTlsHandshakeFailure';

select xpath('//Incidents/ExtraInformation/RemoteLocalTuple/text()',xml_data) from incidents_data where mib_name='ipcsTlsHandshakeFailure';
```

I get a error on the xpath command.

> ERROR:  function xpath(unknown, character varying) does not exist
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

The server is running psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.21 and the libxml2 library is installed on the server.

Am I using the xpath function the wrong way?

Comment: Your `xml_data` column is defined as `var(4096)`.  XML functions like `xpath()` require the `xml` type to  work.  You can try to cast `xml_data` to type `xml` with `select xpath('/mydefns:Incident/mydefns:ExtraInformation/mydefbs:RemoteLocalTuple', xml_data::xml) from incidents_data where mib_name='ipcsTlsHandshakeFailure';`  That will require that all data in `xml_data` is valid xml.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Mike is right, `xpath()` expects a `xml` value, not a `character varying` value. You need to cast it: `xml_data::xml`. The better solution however is to define the column `xml_data` with the type `xml` (btw: the arbitrary limit of 4096 has no storage or performance advantage over any other limit, it only makes sense if you have a business rule that says the XML may never be longer then 4096 characters)

Comment: Thank you Mike Organek

Your answer was correct and resolved the issue. This is a vendor database so we have no say in how the data is added to the table.